# Apache2 + fcgid + virtualmin - Slow website

Tags: apache-http-server, wordpress, debian-jessie, webmin, virtualmin

I have 2 webservers running with Virtualmin, webmin. My problem is I have moved a website from one server to another with Virtualmin's backup restore feature.

After 1-2 days the moved website as I see is painfully slow. 8-9 seconds to load.

PHP version: 5.6.30

MariaDB 10.0.29

I have tried:

```
- Turn OFF CSF's country block
- Turn OFF CSF totally
- Turn OFF Wordpress's WP Super Cache plugin
- Turn OFF Jetpack
- Set PHP execution mode to mod_php (1-2 seconds faster, not a really solution)
- Turn OFF, then ON cloudflare's caching. (My server is behing CloudFlare)
- Set the mod_deflate on htaccess.
- Setup browser cache for 1 month in htaccess
```

Nothing helped. My server is at 5% at CPU 44%of memory.

It's parameters are:

```
Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 on x86_64
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X5670 @ 2.93GHz, 2 cores
Memory: 2.40 GB total / 1.06 GB used
Virtual memory: 1.71 GB total / 26.13 MB used
```

It is a VPS server with 100mbit full duplex connection. Runs only one Wordpress website, with low views (50-80/day)

To load the website there is 96 other requests (JS,CSS,etc) maybe its high, but this is a strong VPS I think. That shouldnt be a problem.

Checked the queries with mytop. There were no slow queries. Right now I have no idea what to do. Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Start from testing disk benchmark (read/write speed), then test plain apache (without php, just static files) with [ab](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html). Test setup locally on VPS via localhost. If it is Ok, then run [MTR](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/mtr) tests to spot network path that misbehave